# Spring Kafka Multiple Consumers for a Partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We are using spring kafka to consume messages. We have created receiver for each partition to receive messages. Now we have requirement where we need more than one receivers to consumer message from single partition.

for e.g. Lets suppose we have a Partition 0. Currently we have only one receiver (Receiver 1) that receives messages from this partition. 
Now I want to add another Receiver (Receiver 2) for the same partition (Partition 0).

So if Producer sends 100 messages to this partition,50 messages should be received by Receiver 1 and remaining 50 messages should be received in Receiver 2. I dont want messages to be duplicated. Both the receiver classes belong to the same group.(I have set  props.put("group.id", "unique_group_id") )

Please help me to understand if this scenario is acheivable.

Answer (score 4):

NO, you **CANNOT** do that. Each partition can only be consumed by only one consumer in a single consumer group.

If you want 2 consumers to consume the same partition, these 2 consumers have to belong to 2 different consumer group. However, in this case, both consumers will receive all messages of this partition.

It seems what you need is a `worker queue`. 2 workers consume messages from a single queue, and each message will be consumed by only one worker. There are many open source `worker queues`, such as `ActiveMQ`, `RabbitMQ`, and so on.

Comment: But we have already finalized technology stack. So cannot replace Kafka with any queue. Do we have any configuration in the kafka broker where i can specify that for producer send only one copy of message irrespective of Consumer group?

Comment: Kafka does not support competing consumers on a partition. Consumer concurrency is limited by the number of partitions. To increase concurrency, simply increase the number of partitions. `> finalized technology stack` - that sounds odd - how can you select a technology without understanding it first?

Comment: @user3811946 There's no such configuration. As Gary Russell said, you have to increase the number of partitions to increase concurrency. Another solution is that, for each consumer, sends data of a partition into a `worker queue`, and then have multiple workers to process these messages. However, this solution is more complicated. Maybe you should reconsider your design.

Comment: if kafka is set in stone as a technology you could use spark streaming to process as one consumer. That way you offset a microservices approach with having multiple consumers to one big spark stream with multiple executors

Answer (score 1):

If you can't increase number of partitions for the topic, there is some "nasty" trick you can use. Use different consumer-group-id in both receivers and after `pool()` discard messages with even offset on one receiver and messages with odd offset on the second one, like this:

```
  R1       R2
| 100      100 [X]
| 101 [X]  101
| 102      102 [X]
| 103 [X]  103
v 104      104 [X]
```

This will work, but has some consequences:

- it is not scalable (you cannot easily add another receiver to the partition)
- if one receiver is stuck/dead, the second one cannot handle it's job
- offsets management on different consumer groups is quite hard (especially if producers are not under your control)